# Run this oracle script in SQL Server which uses tables like V$session and V$sql

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssms

I am trying to make a query which will work similar to this query in SQL Server. I have mentioned the query below.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM v$session session, v$sql sql 
WHERE sql.sql_id(+) = session.sql_id 
  AND session.type = 'USER' 
  AND session.username='<SCHEMA>';'
```

I found the alternative for `V$session` table as `sys.sysprocesses` but what is alternative for `V$sql` in SQL Server? Or is there any way we can get this query using only `sys.sysprocess` table in SQL Server?

Comment: Request if can provide objective, what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Deepak basically it is trying to fetch the number of queries being executed during current session (identified by session_id) through user (schema) whose type is USER(type is a column in v$session table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the sql statement you are looking for..Please modify as per your need..

```
-- Do not lock anything, and do not get held up by any locks. 
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

-- What SQL Statements Are Currently Running?
SELECT [Spid] = session_Id
    , ecid
    , [Database] = DB_NAME(sp.dbid)
    , [User] = nt_username
    , [Status] = er.status
    , [Wait] = wait_type
    , [Pct Done] = percent_complete
    , [Individual Query] = SUBSTRING (qt.text, er.statement_start_offset/2, 
         (CASE WHEN er.statement_end_offset = -1 
            THEN LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), qt.text)) * 2 
          ELSE er.statement_end_offset END - er.statement_start_offset)/2)
    ,[Parent Query] = qt.text
    , Program = program_name
    , Hostname
    , nt_domain
    , start_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests er 
INNER JOIN sys.sysprocesses sp ON er.session_id = sp.spid
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) as qt
WHERE session_Id > 50 -- Ignore system spids. sql
AND 
session_Id NOT IN (@@SPID)  -- Ignore this current statement.
and ecid = 0
ORDER BY start_time, 1, 2
```

Hope this help...

Answer (score 0):

You should likely use a mix of following views:

> sys.dm_exec_requests and/or sys.dm_exec_query_stats  and/or sys.dm_exec_sql_text